# How to fix wrong test controller's filter by status?

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, failing-tests, filters

```
public void byStatus(){
    //Temporary multipicklist, because my main picklist isn't multiselected:
    String temporary = jobAdvertisement.Temporary__c;
    List<String> temporaryList = new List<String>();
    if(temporary != null){
        temporaryList = temporary.split(';');
    }
    //statusList - a list with choosed variants from multipicklist:
    statusList = new List<String>();
    for(String s : temporary){
        statusList.add(s);
    }
status = String.join(soughtStatusList,',');
}

    //Then I use query to make a filter:
    public List<Item__c> mySerch(){
        String[] filters = new String[0];
        if(String.isNotBlank(title)) {
            filters.add('Title__c =: title');
        }
        ... //another if's
        if(String.isNotBlank(status)) {
            filters.add('Field__c =: statusList');
        }
        return Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Item__c'+
                             (filters.isEmpty()?'':' WHERE ' + String.join(filters,' AND ')));
    }

public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
    get {
        if(setCon == null) {                
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(mySerch());
            setCon.setPageSize(size);  
            noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();  //Integer: number of records
        }
        return setCon;
    }
    set;
}

public PageReference refreshPageSize() {
    setCon.setPageSize(size);
    noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
    return null;
}

public Pagereference methodForSearch() {
    setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(mySerch());
    refreshPageSize();
    return null;
}
```

Test:

```
static void test() {
Item__c item = new Item__c(Title__c = 'Test', Status__c = 'New');
List<Item__c> itemList = new List<Item__c>{item};
insert itemList;

PageReference pref = Page.vf;
Test.setCurrentPage(pref);  
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(item);

MyClass.byStatus();
//List<String> statusList = new List<String>{'New'};  //With list it's wrong too

List<Item__c> itemListWithFilters = MyClass.mySerch();
//MyClass.statusList = statusList;
MyClass.title = 'Right Title';
MyClass.status = 'New';

PageReference result = MyClass.methodForSearch();
System.assertEquals(itemListWithFilters, itemList);
System.assertEquals(MyClass.noOfRecords, 1);

}
```

But I get error on this row: my filtered with right parameters list is null. If I use `MyClass.statusList` instead `MyClass.status`, I can write even wrong status there and all is fine. How can I test this part of filter? What I need to check here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void test() {
Item__c item = new Item__c(Title__c = 'Test', Status__c = 'New');
List<Item__c> itemList = new List<Item__c>{item};
insert itemList;

PageReference pref = Page.vf;
Test.setCurrentPage(pref);  
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(item);

MyClass.byStatus();
//List<String> statusList = new List<String>{'New'};  //With list it's wrong too

/*List<Item__c> itemListWithFilters = MyClass.mySerch();
//MyClass.statusList = statusList;
MyClass.title = 'Right Title';
MyClass.status = 'New';*/

//We put it here:
List<String> l = MyClass.statusList;
l.add('New');
String status = String.join(l,',');

MyClass.status = status;

PageReference result = MyClass.methodForSearch();
System.assertEquals(itemListWithFilters, itemList);
System.assertEquals(MyClass.noOfRecords, 1);

}
```

In controller the String isn't just a string: `status = String.join(soughtStatusList,',');` So we need just to model a List with correct status and then make the same string.

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanation to this code?

Comment: Done already...